# Selenium C#. Проблема с WebDriverWait

Tags: c#, selenium, phantomjs

```
private void GetInformation(int seconds)
{
    using (PhantomJSDriverService webDriverService = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService())
    {
        webDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

        using (IWebDriver webDriver = new PhantomJSDriver(webDriverService))
        {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Не удалось найти тип или имя пространства имён WebDriverWait]

Подключил все нужные библиотеки OpenQA.Selenium (3.141.0), OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI (3.141.0), ну и OpenQA.Selenium.PhantomJS (2.45.0.1). Загрузил сам PhantomJS (2.1.1) Устанавливал через NuGet. В итоге у меня VS не видит WebDriverWait. В новом Selenium поменялась реализация неявного ожидания? Кто сталкивался, что делать? Не могу найти похожие ситуации.

Такое чувство противное, что я что-то забыл подключить...

Comment: Сама ошибка: Не удалось найти тип или имя пространства имен "WebDriverWait" (возможно, отсутствует директива using или ссылка на сборку).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Узнал, что неявное ожидание можно реализовать следующим образом:

```
webDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds));
```

> ImplicitlyWait - Определяет количество времени, которое драйвер должен
>   ждать при поиске элемента, если он не присутствует немедленно. (с.
>   англ by google translate)

*Примечание:* **При поиске одного элемента драйвер должен опрашивать страницу до тех пор, пока элемент не будет найден или пока не истечет этот тайм-аут**, прежде чем выдать исключение OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException. **При поиске нескольких элементов драйвер должен опрашивать страницу, пока не будет найден хотя бы один элемент или не истечет это время ожидания.** Увеличение неявного тайм-аута следует использовать разумно, так как это отрицательно скажется на времени выполнения теста, особенно при использовании с более медленными стратегиями определения местоположения, такими как XPath. (с. англ by google translate)